# Ember assets broken in nested route template

Tags: ember.js

I created a nested route under an existing route.

```
Router.map(function(){
 this.route('parentRoute', function(){
    this.route('childRoute');
  });
});
```

Prior to the nesting, I had the newly nested route as a sibling to the now parent route. At the time, I was able to load assets using the normal method

```
<img src="assets/images/profile/pic.svg" alt="" />
```

But after creating the nested route, putting the above in the nested route's template is giving me a 400 file not found error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put "/" in front of assets:

```
<img src="/assets/images/profile/pic.svg" alt="" />
```

Why is that:

If url in src or href property starts with slash, browser interprets this as "site root". If no, browser interprets it as "from current path". So, if current URL is www.site.com/route-one/route-two, "assets/images/profile/pic.svg" becomes "/route-one/route-two/assets/images/profile/pic.svg". Take a look at [this article](http://www.natashabanegas.com/use-absolute-paths-instead-of-relative-to-link-to-css-js-and-media-files/) for better explanation and examples.

**UPD:** If you're using 2.x, it might be better to use `{{rootURL}}` instead of `/`, though it doesn't matter if your app's URL will be a site's root